# functions props change doesn't occurs child component render why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have App, TseTest(which has msg props) components and TseTest have variables a, b and each values have random number and it prints values on console.

When I press button then msg state in App will change `function () {console.log("t");}` to `function () {console.log("tt");}`

And I expected TesTest will rerender due to msg is changed and prins a,b on console with new values but it's not.

It seems props of function type is not occurs render when it changes.

Do you know why?

```
const TseTest = ({ msg }) => {
  const a = Math.random();
  const b = () => Math.random();
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(msg)
    msg && msg();
  }, [msg]);
  return (
    <>
      {console.log("a", a)}
      {console.log("b", b())}
    </>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(function () {
    console.log("t");
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setMsg(function () {
            console.log("tt");
          });
        }}
      >
        test
      </button>
      <TseTest msg={msg} />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

expected

```
t 
a 0.9264919874929558
b 0.5546484347625045
tt
a 0.232132412412...
b 0.6546456...
```

results

```
t 
a 0.9264919874929558
b 0.5546484347625045
tt
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/tender-maxwell-vbtk2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` takes a `function` which is actually used for [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) of state i.e. for the first time whatever is returned from this function will be set to initial state.

```
 const [msg, setMsg] = useState(function () {
    console.log("t");
  });
```

Now you were expecting `msg` to be set as `function` but what's happening is that the returned value from that `function` is being set and which in your case is `undefined` since you're not returning anything.

Similarly,`setMsg` also takes a `function` as it's first parameter which allows access to the `previous state` in it's argument and whatever you return from it is set to `msg`

```
setMsg(function () {
    console.log("tt");
});
```

So in above since you're not returning anything, `undefined` is returned.

So there is no difference in value of `msg` as both times it is `undefined`, thus no re-render.

Here is a forked sandbox which achieves what you want :-

[image: Edit sweet-jepsen-hy779]